# Is there a way to make my API queryable only by my node.js server?

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, api-key, web3js

I am writing an oracle for Ethereum so I have my node.js server where using web3.js I send the http request to my api using axios and then I send the results to my smart contract.

So I would like one way to make sure that only that node.js server can query my API (written in node.js), while others should return status 401 Unauthorized.

(All this with the aim of having to use Ethereum's blockchain to query my api from the outside)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use an authentication middleware in you api end points so only your server can send request with the correct credentials.

Comment: I was thinking about adding an apiKey generated with UUID for example to my axios request and check for that on my API server, would this be a suitable/safe solution? Are there any possible improvements/libraries that could help?